# How to use the Bromwich integral formula for inverse Laplace transforms

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laplace-transform, contour-integration, residue-calculus

How do I use the Bromwich inversion formula to find inverse Laplace transforms?

$$ f(t)=  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int \limits_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} e^{st} F(s)ds $$

I read in a complex analysis book to take only the residues, but how does that work? The "contour" is just a single line. And how do I choose the constant c?

Comment: As written the inversion of a Laplace transform, in terms of contours in general, is covered in most, if not all, modern day Laplace transform books. If there is a particular example that would be more specific to a problem then maybe there would be more of a response by most viewers of this question.

Comment: We must choose $c$ so that it is larger than the real part of any singularity of $F$.  That is, all singularities of $F$ must lie in the plane left of $\text{Re}(s)\ge c$.   Then, one closes the Bromwich contour in the plane that contains the singularities of $F$.

Comment: Actually $c>1$ and I think you choose $c$ so that all poles must cover inside the contour (not fully sure about it). And the contour isn't a single line. Actually, it is a closed curve [1]https://www.desmos.com/calculator/509gn1hdz1